# Ajax Not Working With C# Controller Action With 2D Array Parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My Ajax is not hitting my controller action. What could be the reason?

My Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult Save_Data(string [][] rosterArray, int Pricelist_Id, int Group_Id)
```

My Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save_Data", "PriceListMaster")',
    type: 'Post',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {  "rosterArray": rosterArray, "Pricelist_Id": "2", "Group_Id": $("#Group_Id").val() },
    //data: JSON.stringify({ "Item_Code": Item_Code, "IPD_Price": IPD_Price, "OPD_Price": OPD_Price, "EMS_Price": EMS_Price }),
    success: function (data) {
        debugger
        if (data.success)
        {
            alert('Data Saved Successfully.');
            location.reload();
        } else {
            alert(data.error_msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `rosterArray`?

Comment: stringify the array data: {  "rosterArray": JSON.stringify(rosterArray), ....... and at serverside read it as atring type from which you can phrase it back to array

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `type: 'Post'` in AJAX, that means you need to add a Request type in Controller.

Try using this in controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save_Data(string [][] rosterArray, int Pricelist_Id, int Group_Id)
```

Use `httpPost` in the Method for define type of response.

Comment: Yes this would be a great place to start. If you already have it, try removing all your parameters and see if you hit your action and then add one at the time. But I think the Smit answer would do it.

Answer (score 1):

at client side

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save_Data", "PriceListMaster")',
    type: 'Post',
    async: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {  "rosterArray": JSON.stringify(rosterArray), "Pricelist_Id": "2", "Group_Id": $("#Group_Id").val() },
    //data: JSON.stringify({ "Item_Code": Item_Code, "IPD_Price": IPD_Price, "OPD_Price": OPD_Price, "EMS_Price": EMS_Price }),
    success: function (data) {
        debugger
        if (data.success)
        {
            alert('Data Saved Successfully.');
            location.reload();
        } else {
            alert(data.error_msg);
        }
    }
}
```

and your controller code can be like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save_Data(string rosterArray, int Pricelist_Id, int Group_Id)
{
    string [][] convertedArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string [][]>(rosterArray);
}
```

Hope this works
Note: But you need to incude `using Newtonsoft.Json;`

Comment: You should add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to make it clear that the controller method needs to accept a post (since the client code is making a post).